# How to delete special data from database by python django

Tags: python, django

For example, I have a table called BlackList in the database which looks like this:

[image]

and the model of the table is:

```
class BlackList(models.Model):
    list = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

What I try to do is:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    BL = BlackList.objects.values_list('list', flat=True) # Read all data into array
    if username in BL:  # Check if the username is in blacklist
       # Remove this username from the BlackList table
```

So my question is how to delete the special data for a special, for example, if 'aaa' try to log in, then 'aaa' will be removed or deleted from the BlackList table.

Comment: Not sure what the end goal is here, but with above code you will remove the user from the blacklist even if he **fails** to login.

Answer (score 2):

There is `.delete` method. I. e. try this:

```py
if BlackList.filter(list=username).exists(): 
    BlackList.objects.get(list=username).delete()
```

instead of:

```py
BL = BlackList.objects.values_list('list', flat=True) # Read all data into array 
if username in BL: # Check if the username is in blacklist 
    # Remove this username from the BlackList table
```

You can read more about that on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` in combination with `first()` to get the exist username:

```
blacklist = Blacklist.objects.filter(username=username).first()
```

(This will return `None` if there is no match. If you use `get()`, you will get `DoesNotExist` error instead -- which is not preferred.)

After that, you can just delete it:

```
blacklist.delete()
```

It will take 2 queries (get and delete) to achieve your goal.

An alternative way is to delete it without getting the object:

```
Blacklist.objects.filter(username=username).delete()
```

This statement will be execute with only one query which is equals `DELETE FROM ... WHERE username='username'`